# How to quickly modify python code on larger projects? How to run sections of code in multi-module python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spyder

I am working on a data analysis project with a large data set.  Previously I have been using Run Segment (F9) to run all my code which has made it easy to quickly try different things and debug quickly.

The project has gotten larger so I have separated the functions and sections of code into different modules that I call from main.py in order to reuse functions when analyzing the different diseases and perform the same analysis on different diseases.

How do developers efficiently troubleshoot on bigger projects?  For instance, previously if I filtered a pandas dataframe and got different results than expected I would just change the filter condition and re-run that single line of code.  Now I must entirely reload the data and perform all the prior modifications when I change just one line of code.
If I am changing a function in a second level module such as a helper function, I must restart the kernel for the changes to the module to take effect which takes even longer.

What are some development techniques to allow me to effeciently explore the data and debug my code without having to repeatedly reload/reprocess the dataset?
Python seems to make it quite difficult to reload modules.  What is the intended way to efficiently develop multi module code?

Thanks.

Comment: Reloading modules is almost never the answer. (Some people disagree, but those people refuse to touch any language that isn't Smalltalk.) You want to design all of your tests to be run in a brand-new, clean session, not in the middle of a long interactive session. That forces you to come up with clean interfaces between components. And to organize your data so that what you have at each intermediate stage is something you can understand—and save to a file and restore. All of these things have additional benefits—and, together with any decent unit-test library, they're really all you need here.

Comment: Anyway, once you've got things working, it will often be faster to _not_ save and load everything, and instead just connect things up interactively, and that's fine. As long as it's _possible_ to do clean tests, and save and restore state, you don't have to run them that way every time. If you already have the output `data` from `func1` that you would have saved and restore to pass to `func2` in a variable, and if you can write a replacement `func2` in its own throwaway module, you don't need to reload anything; just import that throwaway and call its `func2` with your `data`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks.  Could you expand some on how to connect the modules interactively?  Even if I save the intermediate dataset, it take 1.46 min to reload into memory.  The machine has 256gb of memory so I would rather just keep it in memory.  If I understand correctly are you saying I should leave the data from `func1` loaded interactively and then call `func2`?  I have tried this and the problem is that `func2` is in a separate module from `main.py`.  Also if you move your comment to an answer then I can accept the answer.

Comment: @abarnert Should I only move code that is already debugged to other modules so that I can quickly troubleshoot code without restarting to reload everything?